# Is it possible to Automate an Excel process in SSIS?

Tags: sql, excel, automation, ssis, ssms

I was wondering if it's possible to automate and process done in excel manually. I want to create an SSIS package that would automate this process. But I haven't seen any similar ideas pop up so I wanted to ask openly.

Comment: You can do it in SSIS but I wouldn't. First you need to create an excel VBA macro to do what you need. Then you get a scheduling tool to call it. For example like this https://officetricks.com/how-schedule-vba-macro-run-daily-automatically-without-opening-excel/

In my opinion SSIS is making it way too complicated.

Comment: I would suggest using powershell instead. https://powershelladministrator.com/2017/12/20/open-excel-file-and-run-macro/